# Rooting An HTC Droid DNA Phone on Verizon Network

Tags: rooting, htc-droid-dna

I have a Droid DNA, running on the Verizon network. I would like to root this phone so I can use some of the more advanced features of Tasker; however, I am very fearful of "bricking" my phone. I see many approaches, which concerns me, because I would feel more comfortable if I could be sure process X is the one to use and works. Here are the particulars of my phone:

```
Model:  Droid DNA
Model #: HTC6435LVW
Android Version: 4.4.2
HTC Sense Version: 5.5
Software # (Build #): 4.09.605.5
Baseband Version: 1.02.01.0818
Kernel Version: 3.4.10-gc345f6f and @ABM101 #1 SMP PREEMPT
```

Can anyone advise me as to the best approach to take, even if it means there is no current software to root my phone with the version it has?

Thanks, FDijohn

Comment: Related: [How do I root my android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device). The device is specifically not in that question/answer, but there are many generic methods that may work for this device.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but I a very leery of trying any generic approach for the fear of "bricking" my phone, which is why I was hoping someone who actually rooted their Droid DNA phone could tell me the steps and software they used.

Comment: [Posts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2314605) say [RevOne works](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42322906). But I did not look at what the steps are.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, and you probably have already rooted it. I'm going to go ahead and answer this for other people's benefit.

I understand the problems, because I have an HTC One M7, Verizon branded. Kingroot
[(Which can be found here)](http://kingroot.net/) worked for my Samsung Galaxy S3, which was running Kitkat (4.4.2). If that one does not work, try [King**o**root](http://kingoapp.com/).They are both reliable, and should work. If you want functionality, use kingroot, but if it is a good UI, use kingoroot. They both are similiar, so it should not matter too much.

Hope this helps.

PS.

If none of that works, then you might want to cough up the $25 for Sunshine S-OFF. It should root , and S-OFF.